# Como hacer el siguiente problema pero con ciclo Do While en Java

Tags: java, bucles

**Una compañía de seguros tiene contratados a n vendedores. Cada uno hace tres ventas a la semana. Su política de pagos
es que un vendedor recibe un sueldo base, y un 10% extra por comisiones de sus ventas. El gerente de su compañía
desea saber cuánto dinero obtendrá en la semana cada vendedor por concepto de comisiones por las tres ventas
realizadas, y cuanto tomando en cuenta su sueldo base y sus comisiones**

Lo hice con ciclo while el problema es que no se como hacerlo
*Usando ciclo do while*

> aqui mi codigo usando while:

````
public class CompañiaSeguros {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double n, x, sueldo, comision, venta1, venta2, venta3;
         
        n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese el numero de vendedores","Vendedores",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        x=1;
        
        while (x<=n){
            sueldo=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese el sueldo base del vendedor: "+x,"Sueldo Base",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese las 3 ventas del mes: ");
            venta1=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Venta 1","Ventas del mes",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            venta2=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Venta 2","Ventas del mes",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            venta3=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Venta 3","Ventas del mes",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        
            comision = (venta1 + venta2 + venta3) * 0.10;
        
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\nEl sueldo mensual es: " + sueldo+"\nLa comisión del mes es: " + comision+"\nEl sueldo con comisión es: " + (sueldo+comision));
           
            x = x + 1;

        }
            
        }        
    }```
````

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Porqué crees que está mal? No hacemos *code review*. Si tienes un problema específico o un error, debes indicarlo en tu pregunta. Decir que algo *crees* que está mal no ayuda a identificar el problema. Te invito a leer [ask]. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo es modificar y poner en el `do` tu codigo que quieras que se ejecute y en el `while` la sentencia
Quedaria asi:

````
public class CompañiaSeguros {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double  sueldoB, comision, venta1, venta2, venta3;
        int n, x;
        n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese el numero de vendedores",
                                                   "Vendedores",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        x=1;
        
        do{
            sueldoB=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese el sueldo base del vendedor: "+x,
                                                                     "Sueldo Base",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese las 3 ventas del mes: ");
            venta1=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Venta 1","Ventas del mes",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            venta2=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Venta 2","Ventas del mes",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
            venta3=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Venta 3","Ventas del mes",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        
            comision = (venta1 + venta2 + venta3) * 0.10;
        
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\nEl sueldo mensual es: " + sueldoB+
            "\nLa comisión del mes es: " + comision+"\nEl sueldo con comisión es: " + (sueldoB+comision));
           
            x = x + 1;
            
        }while (x<=n);
            
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Es de modificar algunas cosas en tu código para que tome forma de la estructura `Do While` en donde el código dentro del `Do {}` es lo primero que se ejecutará y después se evalúa la condición dentro del `While` a la diferencia de la estructura con el simple `While` donde primero se evalúa lo que hay dentro para seguir después con el bloque de instrucciones.

Tu código podría ser adaptado de la siguiente forma que es como mejor recuerdo pues sí ya estoy algo oxidada en Java

```
contador = 0
Escribe el numero de vendedores, nvendedores
Ingrese el sueldo base de los empleados, sueldo
    do {    
        Escribe las tres ventas del mes, v1,v2,v3
        El sueldo mensual es, sueldo
        La comisión es, comision = (v1+v2+v3) * 0.10
        El sueldo con comision es, (comision+sueldo)
        contador=contador+1
    } while (contador<=nvendedores)
```

Espero te sea útil.